# gdalwarp to geographic coordinate system

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I'm getting the folllowing Error when trying to re-project a raster from NAD_1983_Albers to GCS_North_American_1983.  I used the proj4 defenition from going to Properties in QGIS of the layer whose CRS I want to match and copied the CRS def I found in the Coordinate Reference System Selector.

> > gdalwarp -t_srs +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +tow
> >     gs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs RipBuf100_09.tif RipBuf100WGS_09.tif
> >     ERROR 4: `+ellps=GRS80' does not exist in the file system,
> >     and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Answer (score 3):

Using the EPSG works:

> > gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4269 RipBuf100_09.tif RipB
> >     uf100WGS_09.tif
> >
> > Creating output file that is 55104P x 24192L.
> >     Processing input file RipBuf100_09.tif.
> >     Using internal nodata values (e.g. -2.14748e+009) for image RipBuf100_09.tif.
> >     Copying nodata values from source RipBuf100_09.tif to destination RipBuf100WGS_0
> >     9.tif.
> >     0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

Answer (score 1):

shot in the dark, but maybe use the EPSG instead of the actual CRS label

Answer (score 1):

Put the proj4 string between quotes. Now the string gets split at parsing and GDAL thinks that the +ellps is a name of the source file.

Comment: Depending on the operating system, single quote`'` or double quote `"` might be successful.